# Can't connect to rabbitmq server in react-native app

Tags: react-native, rabbitmq

I am trying to integrate rabbitmq on a react native app

Referring to this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rabbitmq

I tried to create a Connection object using the appropriate config properties. But when I tried to check the result of `let connection = new Connection(config);` I received following :

`Connection {rabbitmqconnection: Object, callbacks: Object, connected: false}` in the connection object. As you can see, it gives `connected: false`

I have referred to create rabbit mq server on node side : https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html to create a node rabbit mq server which works properly. Now I need to receive messages on the client side

I am sure of the config properties & rabbitmq server functioning properly because using same I can connect to rabbit mq from a separate node server. Tried to add loggers in both `connection.on('error')` & in `connection.on('connected')` but did not get any log

Unable to understand where the issue is. Can anybody help or suggest a better library? Need to integrate RabbitMQ on react-native

```
const config = {
        host: '192.0.0.1', //dummy values
        port: 5672,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        virtualhost: 'vhost'
    };
    const connection = new Connection(config);
    console.log('connection config changed');
    console.log(connection);
    connection.on('error', (event) => {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(event);
    });

    connection.on('connected', (event) => {
        const queue = new Queue(this.connection, {
            name: 'queue_name',
            passive: false,
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            consumer_arguments: { 'x-priority': 1 }
        });

        const exchange = new Exchange(connection, {
            name: 'exchange_name',
            type: 'direct',
            durable: true,
            autoDelete: false,
            internal: false
        });

        queue.bind(exchange, 'queue_name');

        // Receive one message when it arrives
        queue.on('message', (data) => {
                console.log('Single message received');
                console.log(data);
        });

        // Receive all messages send with in a second
        queue.on('messages', (data) => {
            console.log('Multiple messages received');
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: @PratheeshM Added code snippet in question. Library referred : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rabbitmq

Answer (score 5):

I have been able to connect rabbitmq to my react-native app.
I managed to do this on a windows 10 PC.

**Step 1:** If you have rabbitmq for windows installed, you're good to go, otherwise, go to [https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html) .
Access the **sbin** folder inside your installation files(under program files),
copy the path, e.g. ( `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.4\sbin` )
and add it to your environment variables
(Go to **This PC/My Computer**, right click and select **properties**, click on
**Advanced system settings**, select **environment variables**, under
**system variables**, highlight **path** and click **edit**,
click **new**, then paste the copied path in, and then click **ok**.
The steps above help you to run rabbitmq commands on your cmd

**Step 2:** Access the Rabbitmq folder inside your Roaming folder,

```
C:\Users\PcName\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
```

Open the **enabled_plugins** file and type in the following code:

```
[rabbitmq_management].
```

Save and exit

Open the **config** folder and create a **rabbitmq.config** file inside,

type in the following snippets of code:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672},
    {"::1",       5672}]}
  ]}
].
```

save and close the file

**Step 3:** Access your command line (Run as Admin)
From anywhere on your command line, run the following to set username,
password and admin privileges:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user dummy dummy
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags dummy administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / dummy ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

After that run to enable rabbitmq management:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Once it is done running, run the following:

```
rabbitmq-server
```

it should show "completed with n plugins (where n is a number)

**Step 4:** Open your **App.js** file(in your react-native folder) and replicate the code below:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Connection,
          Queue,
          Exchange
       } from 'react-native-rabbitmq';
       
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    const config = {
      host: '10.0.2.2',
      port: 5672,
      username: 'dummy',
      password: 'dummy',
      virtualhost: '/'
    };

    let connection = new Connection(config)
    connection.connect()

    let connected = false;
    let queue;
    let exchange;
    
    connection.on('connected', (event) => {

      queue = new Queue(connection, {
        name: 'queue_name',
        passive: false,
        durable: true,
        exclusive: false,
        consumer_arguments: { 'x-priority': 1 }
      });

      exchange = new Exchange(connection, {
        name: 'exchange_name',
        type: 'direct',
        durable: true,
        autoDelete: false,
        internal: false
      });

      queue.bind(exchange, 'queue_name');
      
    });

    

    

    connection.on('error', event => {
      
      connected = false;
      console.log(connection);
      console.log(event);
    });

  }
  
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

The host ip (10.0.2.2) is the default android ip (for those running an android emulator).

The connection code had to be put within a componentWillMount() function because it is asynchronous.

**Step 5:** Power up your android emulator and build your react-native app.
There should be no errors on the android screen.

**Step 6:** Access rabbitmq management on your browser via the link below:

```
localhost:15672
```

sign in with your username and password (username: **dummy**, password: **dummy**  in this case), you should see a connection under Connections and a queue(queue_name) under Queues

Cheers.